# Removing Server-Side Event from RadComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, server-side, radcombobox

I'm looking to, in a certain scenario, remove the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event from a Telerik RadComboBox.

When the scenario is satisfied, I'm hoping to remove "myRCB_SelectedIndexChanged" and when it's not, leave the event as-is.

I've tried:

```
myRCB.SelectedIndexChanged -= myRCB_SelectedIndexChanged
```

And:

```
myRCB.SelectedIndexChanged -= new RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(myRCB_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

Neither works, and the event still fires upon changing index. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the replies led me toward the answer (thank you!). I added breakpoints where necessary, watched when/where the Event Handler was added/removed, and found that the user-experience was still as it existed--the page would still post back and would run the `SelectedIndexChanged` event even though the removal was being done and the addition wasn't happening again thereafter.

Doing this, though, gave me the idea to simply disable `AutoPostBack` where I was once attempting to remove the Event Handler. Now, instead of solely defining `AutoPostBack="true"` in the .aspx, I am, additionally, removing it where necessary in the .cs.

I hope this helps somebody else, because this has had me banging my head on the desk for days!

Answer (score 0):

In case of a normal control, the first one should work, assuming the signature is correct, but in this case the control is an external control from a dll (?) and I'm not sure, but could the handlers be populated on each page load?

You could try to disable the handler at page load under certain condition is filled.   For test purposes, tou could for example save the remove condition to a label or a sessoon variable.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the first one does the trick for me. Set a breakpoint to make sure the event handler isn't getting re-added. Otherwise, maybe set a flag on that scenario, and wrap your whole Event Handler method with an if statement.